# how can use SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); after insert statment in mysql routine?

Tags: mysql, xampp

I tried to write routine in xampp.  it made error when I added select statement
but if I run it in queries not in routine it is runs.

```
INSERT INTO product(name,description,unit_price)  VALUES (@name,@description,@unit_price); 
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Comment: I suspect the issue is that the code is attempting to execute two statements (the INSERT and the SELECT) in a single query execution. (That's just a guess. because we don't *see* any code here, just two SQL statements. So we're just guessing. Maybe you've seen this code pattern demonstrated somewhere?) The fix would be to execute the two statements separately, one after the other. (Some one will likely suggest enabling multi-query, but I dis-recommend that approach, as that can throw open the gates to a whole 'nuther gaping chasm of nasty Little Bobby Tables SQL Injection vulnerabilities.)

Comment: Saying "it made error" is next to useless in providing meaningful information about the actual problem. (It is slightly better than "it's not working", at least there's an indication that an error was logged or shown.) To get more concrete help, rather than just guesses,  consider posting the actual code, and including the actual error message.